# Excel: Hide data until date is entered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to prevent a user from seeing the data in cell A1 until they enter the date in cell D1. Once they enter the date in cell D1, the data in A1 will appear for them.

Comment: Use conditional formatting.  Initially format the cell with the text color the same as the back ground, then when a date is added have a conditional format rule that changes the text color to the desired color.

Comment: will the date be entered as an excel formatted date.. or as a text (string)? (some [reference](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_2010/formula-to-check-if-it-is-a-date/39c833d6-94d3-4c83-b3f6-117a5fd20344), if it is useful)

Answer (score 2):

@Scott Craner knows his stuff and he concisely answered your question within the confines of the information you included.  I can't think of anything other than VBA to hide the value of a cell without expanding scope.

> Use conditional formatting. Initially format the cell with the text color the same as the back ground, then when a date is added have a conditional format rule that changes the text color to the desired color. ***– Scott Craner***

Note that the user can still see the data in the formula bar if the cell is selected.  To prevent this, you could hide the formula bar or uncheck the box "select locked cells" and protect the worksheet.

Another thing to keep in mind is cell overflow.  If B1 is empty and A1 contains a large string, then with the default settings, the contents of A1 will flow into adjacent columns.  You cannot see the text if it matches the background of those columns and you cannot select it, but the cell borders are removed which gives the appearance of a merged cell.  And if the background color is changed, then the overflowing text can be read.  You can allign text to the right to prevent overflowing Column B, but that could be a problem if columns will be added to the left.

Alternatively, you can place your data in a hidden sheet and use formulas to present the data when appropriate.  Worksheet protection is still required to prevent a savvy user from prematurely reading the data and be warned that a skilled user can find your data anywhere in the workbook, no matter what you do.

Comment: Since you're answering anyway, you may as well include Scott's suggestion in your answer in-line (with attribution naturally)

Comment: @Alex M Good call. Updated.

Comment: I feel so warm and fuzzy being quoted.  :)  good job expanding on it.

Comment: Using a custom number format of `;;;` is better than a white font on a white background.

Comment: @jeeped I love a clever use of custom number formats as much as anyone but that's not true.  Custom number formats are only applicable in specific situations and we do not know if they can be used here.   We know is cell D1 is a user entered date and that an arbitrary date will trigger visibility of A1; but we do not know what is in A1, it can be any data type of any length that fits in a cell.  Custom number formats cannot handle that variability.  Conditional formatting can.  A solution that works is better than a solution that doesn't work, therefore, your conclusion is false.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious - You can apply a custom number format with a conditional formatting rule.